# Usage of neither in a sentence

Tags: grammaticality, disjunction

Is the sentence "Neither of Jack and Jill is present here" correct? I want to use "neither" and "and" in a sentence.

Comment: _Why_ do you want to use them together?

Comment: Please visit [ell.se]

Comment: Suggesting migration to [ell.se]

Answer (score 2):

The correct phrasing here would be

> **Neither** Jack **nor** Jill are present here.

*I think it's accepted to use "or" instead of "nor". I'm not sure if this is different for UK/US English, or whether it's grammatically as correct. I suspect it isn't as correct, formally speaking.*

You used "Neither of" in your example, which would only fit in a sentence like:

> Jack and Jill? **Neither of them** is present at the moment.

You use "Neither of" when you're using a single statement ("them") to list both people. You use "Neither A nor B" when you separately reference both people ("A", "B").

- **Neither of** the support guys knew about the server issue.
- **Neither** Bill **nor** Bob knew about the server issue.
- **Neither** the nurse **nor** the doctor could understand the foreign patient.

I currently don't see how you can use "neither" **and** "and" in a single sentence to express the same meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Neither has several entries in [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/neither);

You could use the adjective, which (ususally) excludes two-together.

> Neither twin and neither of the other two brothers knew how to knit.

And the conjunction also works (but add nor)

> Neither Jack and Jill, nor Hansel and Gretel got away unscathed.

And the pronoun, as a recapitulation:

> Jack and Jill were neither of them exactly mountaineers.